# audio never lines up with video correctly

Tags: audio, audio-recording

I'm using audacity to record my mic at 44100 hz and using obs studio to record my screen at 60 fps. when I start recording, I enable my mic on obs for a few seconds while audacity is also recording to I can sync them in editing. so I do that later and its aligned well give or take some frames. however, later in the video my mic audio from audacity doesn't align with the video at all. so I align it again at that point using video context clues but then later the same thing happens. I checked obs settings and it says i was recording audio at 48khz (48000hz) the only other option was 44.1khz (44100 as audacity was using) so I switched it to 44.1 but I don't know if it works. I'm pretty confident that this will fix it but I don't have the time to test it so I just want to know if that is what the answer would most likely be.

Comment: Yeah, it is definitely the sample rate difference. Why are you recording at 44.1 and separately in audacity? Definitely record at 48 and you should probably save yourself the trouble and just record the audio in OBS, too.

Comment: that's what it was set to automatically. I record in audacity so I can edit out all the background noise I have. I tried obs's tools for it and a bunch of plugins for it but none of them ever worked very well.

Comment: Couldn't you import a file recorded in OBS into Audacity afterwards, in order to noise reduce it?  Then recombine the video and audio files after that?

Comment: you mean to use another obs window for audio recording?